# c basic struct help needed

Tags: c, struct

I want to copy values into a `struct` using a pointer.

I keep getting segmentation fault from this small piece of code.

```
struct companyInfo
{
    double sharePrice;
    char companyName[100];
}; 

int main()
{
    struct companyInfo * pdata = NULL;
    strcpy(pdata->companyName, "sdfsd");

    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't allocating any space for the struct, just a pointer that is null.

```
struct companyInfo * pdata = NULL; 
pdata = calloc( 1, sizeof(struct companyInfo) ); 
if( pdata != NULL )
    {
    strncpy(pdata->companyName, "sdfsd", sizeof(pdata->companyName) - 1);
    }
```

Note: `calloc()` will also zero out the memory for you, as opposed to `malloc()` which will just allocate. Also, you should check the return of these functions to make sure the pointer is not NULL.

**Important:** Any memory allocated using malloc(), calloc(), ex.. needs to be explicitly freed.

Example:

```
if( pdata != NULL )
    {
    free( pdata );
    }
exit(0);
```

Comment: +1.  But please mention the need to `free` this.  And also that `strncpy` should be used.

Comment: Agreed. I suppose if the author was not allocating I should point out the free as well. Updating, Thanks.

Comment: I agree `strcpy` is the wrong choice, but I'm not sure that introducing someone to the oddities of `strncpy` is the best idea due to the null termination issue.

Comment: @user967797 No problem. If this answered your question you can click the check mark by the answer so that other people see this question as answered and the solution that worked for you.

Comment: what if `char companyName[100];` field definition is changed into `char companyName[5];` ?? Please change your call to `strncpy` to correctly handle such a case.

Answer (score 1):

`companyInfo` is a pointer to a struct, and that pointer is pointing to `NULL`.  So when you try to dereference it, you get the seg fault.  You either need to use `malloc` to allocate some space for the struct pointer to point to, or declare the struct on the stack.

For the purposes of your exercise, I would go with option 2, as it's simpler.  Just do:

```
int main()
{

    struct companyInfo pdata;
    strcpy(pdata.companyName, "sdfsd");

    exit(0);
}
```

Because there is no `*` after `companyInfo`, `pdata` is not a pointer to a struct, but a struct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int main() {
    struct companyInfo pdata;
    pdata.companyName = "sdfsd";
}
```

You can set all variables in the struct at once:

```
struct companyInfo pdata = { 2.3425, "company" };
```

Tip: Use typedef before using a struct:

```
typedef struct companyInfo companyInfo;
```

So you don't have to type "struct companyInfo" every time. You can now simply use:

```
companyInfo pdata;
```

Hope I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with using a struct, but with trying to use a null pointer. Try something like this:

```
struct companyInfo *pdata = malloc(sizeof(*pdata));

strcpy(pdata->name, "sdfsd");
```